# Identify first character in a string

Tags: php, string

Hello I need help in identifying the first character of a string. if the string contains a forward slash "/" or no forward slash in php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at [this section](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) of the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function getSlashes($str)
    {
        return $str[0] ==  '/' || $str[0] ==  '\\';
    }
```

Comment: `return $str[0] ==  '/' || $str[0] ==  '\\';`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
<?php
function containSlash($str)
{
  return substr($str, 0, 1) == "/";
}

// TEST
echo (containSlash("/hello") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); // TRUE
echo (containSlash("hello") ? "TRUE" : "FALSE"); // FALSE
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two different questions here.

You can examine the first character of a string using

```
$str[0]
```

You can check whether a string contains no `/` by using

```
strpos($str, '/') === FALSE
```