# Selecting an uncommented line from a text file

Tags: php, file, loops, comments

I have a text file full of proxy servers. Some are commented with a # at the beginning and should not be used. I have tried to do this using the code below, but it is still picking commented lines. Where am I going wrong?

```
function getProxy()
{
    $file = file('proxy.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    $line = $file[array_rand($file)];

    if (strpos($line,'#') !== FALSE) { getProxy(); }

    return $line;
}
```

Ideally I think the code should probably do some form of while loop until it picks a proxy (at random) which does not have a # at the beginning - rather than calling the function each time and reloading the file.

Help!

Comment: What is your question? [How to detect the first char in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394282/identify-first-character-in-a-string) or [How to shuffle an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909116/php-random-array-random-again-when-doing-while) or [How to write a loop?](http://php.net/foreach)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

true - loop is better here:

```
function getProxy()
{
    $file = file('proxy.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    do {

       $line = $file[array_rand($file)];

    } while(strpos($line,'#') !== FALSE);

    return $line;
}
```

you must also add some additional condition -  if file have only commented lines it will now create infinite loop, so better idea would be:

```
function getProxy()
{
    $maxChecks=100;
    $i=0;
    $file = file('proxy.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    do {
       $line = $file[array_rand($file)];
       if($i++>$maxChecks) break;
    } while(strpos($line,'#') !== FALSE);

    if($i>$maxChecks)
       return false;

    return $line;
}
```

Comment: -1 because all you need to do is `shuffle` the array once after you read it and then just foreach over it. It doesn't need any max checks. All it needs is http://pastebin.com/uyaeu39e

Comment: true but on the other hand `shuffle` will take more time for big files than couple of `array_rand` - problem only would be with big number of commented lines

Comment: also, if you just need a single entry from that array, you can just as well run the initial array through `array_filter` and then `array_rand` it and be guaranteed to get a valid entry.

Comment: Both solutions are not really good. The first one can possibly run in an nearly-endless loop, the second one might return no result although there is one in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best way to handle the problem is to remove any line that is commented, and only then pick a random result.

Otherwise you might have a very bad luck streak or a file with thousands of commented lines and one or two active, and will wait for hours to have the randomness pick the one line that is valid.

```
function getProxy()
{
    $file = file('proxy.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    foreach ($file as $key => $line) {
        if (strpos(ltrim($line), "#") === 0) {
            unset($file[$key]);
        }
    }

    $line = $file[array_rand($file)];

    return $line;
}
```

You can use `array_filter()` instead, like this:

```
$file = array_filter($file, function($value){return !(strpos(ltrim($value), "#") === 0);});
```